# Why does Application.GetResourceStream always return null in WP7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, embedded-resource

I am creating a Windows Phone app and I will be storing level data in the text files.

I have the following problem: I am trying to read all the lines from the file and every time I call `Application.GetResourceStream` it returns `null`.

I know this topic was asked by different people, but all the solutions didn't work for me.

This is the code:

```
List<String> fileLines = new List<string>();
var resource = Application.GetResourceStream(
                         new Uri("Level_data/Level_1.txt", UriKind.Relative));
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(resource.Stream);
string line;
while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
    fileLines.Add(line);
```

Also, the solution explorer looks like this. The Build Action is set to "Resource", but I also tried "Content" first and didn't work either.

Comment: What's your file compile action? (not visible on screenshot)

Comment: I mentioned in the text. Build Action is 'Resource'.

Comment: Sorry, I must have skipped that line. Any reason why you're not using the Content system that is built into XNA?

Comment: How would it work with the Content system built into XNA? Also I solved it, but still it would be useful if you say how you would do it.

Comment: Well, you would add your file to the Content project instead of the code project. Then you get your file at runtime using the ContentManager, which is created for you in the default Game class (Game.Content).

Comment: Ok, I understand. I was aware that I will have about 200 files. Therefore I wanted to read only the file I need for the current level. My intention was not to use Content Manager to make it more efficient. I hope that my solution is doing what I wanted, but I would need to consult more experienced MS developer to make sure.

Comment: If you're parsing text files at runtime, your solution is hardly efficient. If you want to be efficient, you can create Content Processors to compile your files into more useful data.

Comment: Also would it be better to Load the data from the files in LoadContent method? I could for example create a list of objects. One object will be representing a file. Is it better?

Comment: LoadContent is the usual place yes. I cannot really help you with your design because I'd need to know much more about your game. I'd say do not worry too much about it, until you feel some pain (performance, convenience, maintenability, etc...)

Comment: Ok, many thanks for all the help. I won't worry too much now as it should be a light game at the end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code worked:

```
    Uri u = new Uri("WindowsPhoneGame1;component/Level_data/Level_1.txt",
                                                             UriKind.Relative);
    StreamResourceInfo sInfo=Application.GetResourceStream(u);
    StreamReader sr=  new StreamReader(sInfo.Stream);
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
         fileLines.Add(line);
    sr.Close();
```

The only reason why it wasn;t working earlier was that the Path for the Uri was wrong.
Now it is: `WindowsPhoneGame1;component/Level_data/Level_1.txt` i.e. `(ProjectName);component/(RelativePath)`